# Providing location to Cargo.toml for fmt pre-commit hook

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, rustfmt

I have repository that has both Python and Rust code inside.

In the root of the repository I have `.pre-commit-config.yaml` with:

```yaml
  -   repo: https://github.com/doublify/pre-commit-rust
      rev: master
      hooks:
        -   id: fmt
            args: ['--manifest-path', 'rust_code/Cargo.toml']
```

In the `rust_code/` folder I have rust code together with `Cargo.toml`.

However, it looks like the hook expects `Cargo.toml` to be in the root of the repository and is ignoring arguments.

```
Error during execution of `cargo metadata`: error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `D:\projects\project-repo` or any parent directory
```

What options do I have?

Comment: Looks like this would end-up as [`cargo fmt -- --manifest-path rust_code/Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/doublify/pre-commit-rust/blob/c9d5fe3776c92519e0b7eb9175fb56400f2a518f/hooks.yaml#L4) with an extra `--`. I would open an issue on that repository.

Comment: looks like [there's a PR to fix this as well](https://github.com/doublify/pre-commit-rust/pull/9/files)

Comment: @AnthonySottile Yep, it was provided right after my [issue report](https://github.com/doublify/pre-commit-rust/issues/8).